# Approach for managing multiple git version control repos?

Tags: git

I maintain different git repos for each platform I support.  If I discover a bug on one platform, the fix has to be replicated to all the other platforms.  This seems error prone.

Is there a known good approach in dealing with this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shared repo for the shared code. Then you can use git submodules. Otherwhise, the git remote feature might be good for you

Comment: Just read up on submodule and it seems to be what I need. However, can you elaborate a bit on remote ?    Suppose in a team environment, you would have a remote origin set up on a server for the team to push to and pull from. How would you recommend configuration wise in such setting with submodule?

Comment: well when you have to "fix a bug on one platform and have to replicate it to other platforms", this indicates that you have to copy-paste the code. if possible, you should try to have a git repository for that shared code and the platform-specific projects just include this git repository (even if it is 90% of the codebase) as a submodule.

Comment: Remote was meant to be an alternative, where you have several code repositories that look very similar and have for example a subfolder with the shared code. by using remotes, you could change the code and then just say `git push ios master` `git push android master` and so forth

Comment: agreed. submodule is more suitable to host the common code base to be shared by android and ios repos. Thanks, Tomen!

Comment: you are welcome. i hope for you that 'PG' has matured since i last heard from it about 1 1/2 years ago.